# Zip settings. How to concatenate results from multiple zip files?

Tags: windows-8.1, cygwin, zip, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

So I was one of those fools that didn't realize that Windows 8.1 has removed the windows 7 recovery option for restoring old backups. Now I have a backup set (A folder containing ~1500 zip files) which I am trying to manually recover.

The kicker is that these zips contain hundreds of files >200MB, which means they span more than one zip file. Searching through here and other forums, I only see "extract each zip individually, name the spanned file differently for each zip, then manually concatenate the files in to one." Due to the number of files I have, this is not possible for me.

So what are my options? I have cygwin installed, so I was hoping to use some linux magic to solve my dilemma, though I'm stuck on how to implement this plan.

This is what I'm trying to do:

- Unzip each archive in numerical order
- If a file in the archive with the same name is found, extract and concatenate it to the existing version

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Windows backup features, but if you get desperate perhaps setting up a Windows 7 trial in a virtual machine would get you access to the program you need? Toss the virtual machine once you've recovered your files. If you need a Win7 ISO see this answer = http://superuser.com/a/305434/363072